# How to add my application to app store with two different versions (free and paid)

Tags: ios, itunes

I will publish my app as free, but some parts(functions) of App's will require money.

Ex: when user wants to send message from the app, my app will say

"You should buy full version of this app" ...  etc.

How can i do that. 
I have no idea.

**ANSWER**

I have finally found what i was looking for.
Here is a good article for who are searching the same thing with me.
Thx.

[How to Create Both a Paid and Lite Version of an iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sergio pointed out, you will need two completely different apps.

However, they can - and hopefully will - have the exact same code, except for one single line:
Something like `#define FULL_VERSION` and/or undef.
Then in your real code, you can check for the macro by using `#ifdef`s and `#endif`s and running/compiling code depending on whether the user bought the full version or the 'demo'.

Note that this approach does not affect the runtime speed of your app, while in-app-full-version-purchase would.

```
    BOOL triesToAccessCoolFeature;
    if (triesToAccessCoolFeature)
    {
#ifdef FULL_VERSION
       coolFeature();
#else
       alert("Buy the full version to access this feature.");
#endif
    }
```

Comment: You may already know this, but if you have the exact same code - or very similar code - your apps can be a single XCode Project, with two or more Targets.  The Targets can each define which source files and resources they need.  If you use #defines as @Jenox suggests, these can be put in the Build Settings for the appropriate Target.

Comment: Thanks for answers Jenox.So when the paid app downloanded by user, free app shouldnt be seen. it must be removed automoticly. How can i do that? and how shall i put my paid apps link in my code. It should be directly download link!!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to hide the demo from the AppStore once the user purchased the full version. You simply can't do that.

Comment: As @yatanadam said, you'd want to have a single project with multiple targets, while one of them (the full version) defines the macro `FULL_VERSION`. Check my answer for some example code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two different apps for the App Store: a free and a paid one. You can have, e.g.:

1. MyApp Lite (free) + MyApp (paid)
2. MyApp (free) + MyApp Pro (paid)

The two apps would share a lot of code, but only you will know that. As to the App Store, they would be two completely different and unrelated apps.

In your free app you can add your alert which optionally  can include a link to the App Store page for your paid version.